# How to pass parameters in a stage call in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, stage

Actually my Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
@Library('my-libs') _
myPipeline{
                my_build_stage(project: 'projectvalue', tag: '1.0' )
                my_deploy_stage()
                
                
}
```

I am trying to pass these two variables (project and tag) to my build_stage.groovy, but it is not working.

What is the correct syntax to be able to use $params.project or $params.tag in my_build_stage.groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code which will pass parameters.
In your Jenkinsfile write below code:

```
// Global variable is used to get data from groovy file(shared library file)
def mylibrary
def PROJECT_VALUE= "projectvalue"
def TAG = 1
pipeline{
agent{} 
stages{
       stage('Build') {   
            steps {
              script {
                        // Load Shared library Groovy file mylibs.Give your path of mylibs file which will contain all your function definitions
                        mylibrary= load 'C:\\Jenkins\\mylibs'
                        // Call function my_build stage and pass parameters
                        mylibrary.my_build_stage(PROJECT_VALUE, TAG )   
                      }               
                  }
        }
        
        stage('Deploy') {   
            steps {
              script {
                        // Call function my_deploy_stage
                        mylibrary.my_deploy_stage()   
                      }               
                  }
        }
   }
}
```

Create a file named : mylibs(groovy file)

```
#!groovy
// Write or add Functions(definations of stages) which will be called from your jenkins file
def my_build_stage(PROJECT_VALUE,TAG_VALUE)
 {
    echo "${PROJECT_VALUE} : ${TAG_VALUE}"
 }

def my_deploy_stage()
 {
    echo "In deploy stage"
 }
return this
```

Comment: @codecex does the solution I provided works for you